# Can you concatenate a string value multiple times in a PostgreSql SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Sql Server you can run the following query to combine values from multiple rows into a single string variable.

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT TOP 5 @x = @x + name + ', '
FROM sys.objects

SELECT @x
```

Which results in

"sysrscols, sysrowsets, sysclones, sysallocunits, sysfiles1,"

Is there a way to do something similar in PostgreSql?  I've tried creating a PostgreSql function that does a SELECT INTO stringVariable but that is only resulting in a single row's worth of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.  The code you have in SQL Server is not actually guaranteed to work.  In Postgres, you would use:

```
select string_agg(name, ', ')
from sys.objects;
```

If you have a `sys.objects` table.

Note that in SQL Server, you should do the same thing:

```
select string_agg(name, ', ')
from sys.objects;
```

[as demonstrated in this SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7131b6ed8145a656b7a770c0769dfddb).

As a note:  Your use of the variable is directly contradicted by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> If a SELECT statement returns more than one row and the variable references a non-scalar expression, the variable is set to the value returned for the expression in the last row of the result set.

That said, I know what you are doing actually works in practice.  But I would recommend using `string_agg()` or in earlier versions using XML for string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, string_agg() is what I was looking for.